# check_oracle_health with OPS$Nagios account

Tags: linux, database-administration, nagios

I can login to my database via sqlplus with the OPS$ account, but i cannt seem to get it to work in with the nagios check_oracle_health. Im testing from the command line.

```
nagios@servername:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ sqlplus /@TESTDB

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Fri Jan 30 12:15:59 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select user from dual;

USER
------------------------------
OPS$NAGIOS
```

Logon in using a username and password does work, but isn't allowed in the policy of the company i'm working for.

```
nagios@servername:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ./check_oracle_health --connect=read/pw@TESTDB--mode=connection-time
OK - 0.22 seconds to connect as READ| connection_time=0.2174;1;5

nagios@omonopsview:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ./check_oracle_health --connect=/@TESTDB --mode=connection-time
CRITICAL - cannot connect to /***@TESTDB. ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

nagios@servername:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ./check_oracle_health --connect=TESTDB --mode=sql --name="select user from dual;"
CRITICAL - cannot connect to TESTDB. ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)

nagios@servername:/usr/local/nagios/libexec$ ./check_oracle_health --connect=OPS\$nagios@TESTDB --mode=connection-time
CRITICAL - cannot connect to OPS$nagios@TESTDB. ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist (DBD ERROR: OCIServerAttach)
```

Anyone got an idea what I am doing wrong??